# retriever data from python file and using it in js

Tags: javascript, python, django, geojson

I have this in my `views.py`:

```
import json
import requests


def geojsonFun(request):
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/villeLis/')

    data = r.json()

    geojson = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [d["coordonate_x"], d["coordonate_y"]],
                },
                "properties": d,
            } for d in data]
    }

    # print(geojson)
    return HttpResponse(geojson)
```

I used serializers to have the json file from my mysql database and the link is working, the problem i am not able to see my points on the map on my `dashboard.html` here is a part of it:

```
<script>
        var geojson = geojson;
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoieW9zcmFqYWJyaSIsImEiOiJjazh4M3duc3AwMnJhM2VzMmxjOThxa2F6In0.OAugyooi_oKgzRTznR4eyw';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [9.5, 36.5],
            zoom: 7
        });

        map.addSource(currentKey, { 
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": geojson,
            cluster: true 
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'points',
            source: 'pointsSource',
            type: 'circle',});
</script>
```

I want retrive the result of the function in python and use it as geojson in the js.

Answer (score 0):

in addLayer, you mentionned that source is `pointsSource` but the source name that you have is 'currentKey' and you have to put the name as string